# What are good DynamoDB keys for the next situation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Imagine I use DynamoDB and have the next simple data categories: "seller", "buyer" and "deal".
Naturally both seller and buyer should recieve lists of deals they are engaged in and have possibility to change particular deal. A deal itself should possess information about whom should it be grateful for its existence to.
I think to create own table for deals with the next keys:

```
Primary key:
partition: sellerId,
sort: dealId

Additional index key:
partition: buyerId,
sort: dealId
```

Thus, as I understand I can query engaged deals list for both seller/buyer providing seller/buyer ids and also effectively access particular deal.
Is such structure possible and effective or a better solution can be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you will have plenty more deals than sellers, in this case I suggest you to invert your primary key to;

```
Hash Key: dealId
Sort Key: sellerId
```

This way you make sure to spread your data through more partitions. It would be even better if `dealId` was a random generated number, a GUID for example.

Remember that capacity provisioning is shared among your partitions, so if you have 100 read units reserved and your table needs two partitions but 75% of the data is in partition A and 25% in partition B, then it means you will end up wasting capacity and you are likely having `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException`.

You will still be able to have two additional global secondary indexes with different hash/sort keys, which you'll can use to retrieve the lists of deals by seller/buyer.

Comment: I always thought partition distribution is so important. Until read offication doc today - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions According to it ( readCapacityUnits / 3,000 ) + ( writeCapacityUnits / 1,000 ) = initialPartitions (rounded up). That means that in 100% applications I create there is only one partition.

Comment: So in reality there is no sense at all in uniform keys and uniform partition distribution and algorithmical complexity of the request is the only thing I should care before I'm going to create systems for 10k+ users.

Comment: There are additional conditions in which DynamoDb creates new partitions, some of them being; 1. your table exceeds 10GB (shared with any local secondary indexes), 2. You provision more than 1000 read/write capacity units. If you are sure you are not reaching these limits then your design seems good enough.

Comment: You should also consider that; 1. Partitions are not shrunk after data has been split into multiple partitions. Neither by reducing table size nor by decreasing read/write capacity units. 2. Read/write capacity is evenly divided among partitions, so that you may end up exceeding the partitions capacity limit and thus facing “ProvisionedThroughputExceededException” even if you are not exceeding the table capacity.

Comment: According to your example I need to break algorithmically efficient solution and make scans for an ordinary situations like "get list of deals for a particular seller/buyer" just for a potential situation that someday when my app reaches 10k users this structure will be more efficient.

Comment: If this scenario is hypothetical for your case then ---> "If you are sure you are not reaching these limits then **your design seems good enough**"

Comment: Also, instead of scans you can query global secondary indexes.
I just made sure to warn you of the consequences of not having a primary key that can be evenly spread across partitions. If these consequences does not apply to you then you are good to go. And honestly Id do the same in your scenario.

Comment: If I'm sure that I will have 1 partition in any situation should I think of partion key as still an effective one or not? Or should I consider sort key to be much more important? Amazon doc attracts so much attention to partitioning but tells very little about how that partition/sort keys work inside one particular partition.

Comment: There are still consequences in choosing you primary key, for example; if you want to load a single deal by id you will still need a sellerId at all times

Comment: The point is; designing a DynamoDb table is very hard and full of trade offs